# Create New SMB Share for every folder in a directory using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, smb

I want to create a new SMB Share for every folder in a directory under windows, have the smb share name be the same as the folder name and set the account "Everyone" with "Full Acess" for the share permission (so not the NTFS permissions)

So for example I have the following folders

- Folder1
- Folder2
- Folder3

And the share names should then be named adequately, so Folder1, Folder2, Folder3

I know how to create a single smb share and set a local user with full access with the following:

```
New-SmbShare -name "Test" -path "D:\Test" -FullAccess "TestServer\TestAccount"
```

Where I currently fail is to somehow get all the folder names and create a share accordingly. Also, I don't know how to tell PowerShell the account "Everyone".

EDIT:

When I try it as you mentioned, I get the following error

```
New-SmbShare: The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.

At line:2 char:1
+ New-SmbShare -Name $_.Name -Path $._FullName -FullAccess Everyone
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_SMBShare:ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/SMB/MSFT_SMBShare) [New-SmbShare], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 1789,New-SmbShare
```

Since I can set the permission for this group manually, I dont know why I here would need access to the domain.
I know that the Well-Known SID "World" or "Everyone" has the String Value S-1-1-0, maybe you have to replace "-FullAccess Everyone" with "FullAccess S-1-1-0"? But that didn't work for me..

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/well-known-sids

EDIT2
OS is in german, so I have to change "Everyone" to the german counterpart (="Jeder")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Get-ChildItem -Directory` to enumerate all the folders:

```
Get-ChildItem path\to\root\directory -Directory |ForEach-Object {
  New-SmbShare -Name $_.Name -Path $_.FullName -FullAccess Everyone
}
```

---

To generate the correct translation of `Everyone` regardless of OS language, use its well-known SID:

```
$everyoneSID = [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]::new('S-1-1-0')
$everyoneName = $everyoneSID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value

Get-ChildItem path\to\root\directory -Directory |ForEach-Object {
  New-SmbShare -Name $_.Name -Path $_.FullName -FullAccess $everyoneName
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much and sorry for the back and forth with this comment, when I try it with 
"-FullAccess Everyone" 
I get the error as mentioned in my edit above.

With a local user is works perfectly fine.

Comment: I found my own error, since my OS is in german I have to change "Everyone" to "Jeder", now it worked

Again thank you very much

Comment: @bakersfield That's great, I also added a method for obtaining the correct translation regardless of OS language :) If my answer solves you problem, consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left

Comment: Totally forgot to mark it as accepted, sorry :)
And thanks again for the method regardless of OS language